# How can I access a specific NIC IP address based on a var defined in my playbook?

Tags: ansible, var, ansible-facts

I have different playbooks defined, using the same ROLE.
In one of the ROLE templates, I have to write the IP address of a specific NIC card, which is defined in my playbook because it depends on the host.

So, In my playbook I have defined this var:

```
vars:
      # NIC I want to use
      - nic_card: ens192
```

And in my ROLE main.yml file, I tried to do that:

```
host_specific_address: "{{ ansible_facts['ansible_{{ nic_card }}']['ipv4']['address'] }}"
```

As you can see I tried to define the **host_specific_address** using **ansible_facts** and **nic_card** var.

Unfortunately that didn't work as expected. I tried other combinaisons but I think I'm on the wrong way.

How can I access a specific NIC IP address based on a var defined in my playbook?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: _Unfortunately that didn't work as expected_ – do you have any error or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
specific_address: "{{ ansible_facts[nic_card]['ipv4']['address'] }}"
```

- when you are accessing facts via the ansible_facts dictionary, they are not prefixed by 'ansible_'
- when you are specifying the key of a dictionary using the contents of a variable, you don't wrap in either quotes or `{{}}` Specifying a literal string = `some_dict['key_name']` versus specifying a key based on a string stored in a variable = `some_dict[var_containing_key_string]`

Comment: Amazing clockworknet, that helps me a lot for this task and for the other one!